# Nginx Permission Issues on Centos 7 with Gunicorn Socket in Systemd

Tags: nginx, flask, centos, gunicorn, digital-ocean

We've searched countless threads to solve this problem, but none seems worked for us.
Can anyone help me with this nginx permission issues?
I've installed it with non-root user as suggested in this article.

[How To Serve Flask Applications with Gunicorn and Nginx on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-7)

**However,  we could never be able to access the socket neither the static files.**

Taken from `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`, it always produces **502 Bad Gateway Error** while accessing the socket

`*5 connect() to unix:/home/devops/article-prod/articles.sock failed (13: Permission denied)`

and producing **403 Forbidden Error** while accessing static files

`*14 open() "/home/devops/article-prod/assets/icons/types/article.png" failed (13: Permission denied)`

Here are our permissions path

```
/home/devops/article-prod/
/home/devops/article-prod/articles.sock
/home/devops/article-prod/assets
/home/devops/article-prod/assets/icons
/home/devops/article-prod/assets/icons/types
/home/devops/article-prod/assets/icons/types/article.png

drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root     34  Mar 15 03:57 home
drwxr-xr-x. 6 devops nginx  172 Mar 15 05:38 devops
drwxr-xr-x. 6 devops nginx  197 Mar 15 07:56 article-prod
srwxrwx---. 1 devops nginx    0 Mar 15 06:03 articles.sock
drwxr-xr-x. 3 devops nginx   19 Mar 15 04:56 assets
drwxr-xr-x. 4 devops nginx   36 Mar 15 04:56 icons
drwxr-xr-x. 2 devops nginx   25 Mar 15 04:56 types
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 devops nginx 1718 Mar 15 04:56 article.png
```

FILE nginx.conf:

```
...
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
...
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.article.com;

    location /assets/ {
        root /home/devops/article-prod;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/devops/article-prod/articles.sock;
    }
}
...
```

FILE articles.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve articles
After=network.target

[Service]
User=devops
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/devops/article-prod
Environment="PATH=/home/devops/article-prod/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/devops/article-prod/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:articles.sock -m 007 wsgi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've also did this to make sure devops user is within nginx group

`sudo usermod -a -G devops nginx`

and even the otherway around

`sudo usermod -a -G nginx devops`

but still doesn't work.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to disable SELINUX ? check your SELINUX status by running:

```
$ sudo sestatus
```

if the status is `enabled` you can disable it (temporary) by running:

```
$ sudo setenforce 0
```

and edit file `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` and then change `SELINUX=enforcing` into `SELINUX=disabled` to disable it permanently.

you can restart your server if you want.

hope this will help you

Comment: I don't think it is appropriate for the "solution" to a specific security related problem is to just disable security for the whole host.